# Why is rowCount always 0, when i update my user table whit the following statment

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I want to update some user data in a mysql database, using a html form but the alerted number is always 0. But using the command in phpmyadmin it's working.
Maybe the prepare statment doing something wrong with my parameters?

```
function updateUser($newemail, $name, $email) {
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("update user set name=:name, email=:newemail where email=:email");
    $stmt->bindValue(":newemail", $newemail, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $stmt->bindValue(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $stmt->bindValue(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $stmt->execute();

    $x =$stmt->rowCount();
    echo "<script>alert($x);</script>";
}
```

I am calling the function like this. so they new variables must be different:

```
if( (strcmp($newemail,$email) != 0) ||  (strcmp($newname,$name)!= 0) ){
    $this->db->updateUser($newemail, $name, $email);
}
```

Comment: If `:name` and `:newemail` are the same as they were originally, it won't make any changes and the row count will be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the function with the wrong name variable. You're giving the old name instead of the new name, so it's not changing the name.

```
if( (strcmp($newemail,$email) != 0) ||  (strcmp($newname,$name)!= 0) ){
    $this->db->updateUser($newemail, $newname, $email);
}
```

Comment: Yeah you're right... right now i found the mistake myself... Thank you btw.